# What does `associated_item_id` (Id of the associated item) mean in `sales_order_tax_item`?

Tags: magento2, database, tax, tax-class

Could someone please explain the difference between `associated_item_id` (**Id of the associated item**) and `item_id` (**Item Id**) in **`sales_order_tax_item`** table?

What does **Id of the associated item** mean?

Thank you!